# Origin of slang "doing a bid" for prison time?

Tags: etymology, slang

Going to prison is called "doing a bid".  What's the history behind that?  Is it based on "doing bird" (based on being locked up like a bird)?

Comment: It's not exactly common, but it does seem to be very much a recent Americanism. My guess is it probably originates in a misrendering of the British "doing bird" (which *never* includes the indefinite article).

Comment: It is definitely "bid"? Not "bit", as in "doing a bit of bird" or "doing a bit of time"? Or maybe even a misrendering of that?

Comment: @Andrew Leach: It's not common (I certainly never heard it before), but [doing a **bit**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22doing+a+bid%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) definitely does exist with this meaning. I notice several instances of words like *ain't cool, niggas, mom, upstate* in the surrounding context of those citations, which is why I say it's American.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that 'doing a bit' goes back to the early 20th century as a term for serving a prison sentence.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bit#Noun

'Bit' meaning a short span of time goes back to the 17th century, and presumably that's how it became associated with prison in the first place. "I've got to do a bit of time in prison."

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bit&searchmode=none

I can't find any real resources as to where 'bid' came from directly, so I would assume that it is simply a result of the word shifting slightly once having gained distinct enough usage separate from its origins.

Answer (score 3):

Hollywood once again gets it wrong. It is most emphatically called "doing a bit", not a bid. If your sentence is 10 years it's easier to do it bit by bit, when in prison anything done to pass the time is called bittin. I should know because I did a bit. I can assure you it wasn't an auction.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the company one keeps "doing a bid" isn't uncommon at all.

For example in the lyrics for [Slippin’ by DMX](https://genius.com/Dmx-slippin-lyrics).